# How to extract only files and not directory heirarchy

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How to extract only files and not directory heirarchy.
Suppose I have a myarchive.tgz file which has many directories in it and inside each directory their are files.

```
 eg.myarchive.tgz/folder1/file1.txt                
                 /folder2/folder2.1/file2.txt
```

Now whenever I extract it gets in directory with the same heirarchy it's in archive.
I want to extract like

```
myarchive/file1.txt
         /file2.txt
```

like this.
How to do it? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could unpack the tarball to a temporary folder:

```
rm -rf /tmp/foo && mkdir /tmp/foo # make sure the folder exists and is empty
tar xf foo.tgz -C /tmp/foo
```

Then copy over the files to the final location:

```
rm -rf unpacked && mkdir unpacked # make sure the folder exists and is empty
find /tmp/foo -type f -exec cp -v {} unpacked \;
```

---

Note: `tar -C` is specific to GNU tar. If your tar doesn't understand `-C` use:

```
cd /tmp/foo
tar xf foo.tgz
```

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Added the necessary `\;`

Comment: probably better to use "+": `find ... -type f -exec cp -v {} unpacked +`

Comment: oh, and use `mktemp -d` to "make sure that the folder exists and is empty"

Comment: Creating temporary files and folders is highly platform dependent, mktemp for example is not specified by posix. Same for the `+` instead of the `;`. Therefore optimizations are left to the OP